# Extracting rows from dataframe R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a small problem. I managed to create data frame from two other dataframes which is nice but I have too many rows. Example:

```
**PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F109|2017-05-14|F106|2017-09-05**
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F109|2017-05-14|F106|2017-09-07
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F109|2017-05-14|F106|2017-09-11
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F109|2017-05-14|F106|2017-09-14
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F109|2017-05-14|F107|2018-03-04
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F109|2017-05-14|KB|2018-05-13
**PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F106|2017-09-05|F109|2017-09-06**
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F106|2017-09-05|F109|2017-09-10
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F106|2017-09-05|F109|2017-09-12
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F106|2017-09-05|F109|2017-09-17
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F106|2017-09-05|F107|2018-03-04
PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F106|2017-09-05|KB|2018-05-13
**PL|WPLF05652203|Terytorium_nowe|F109|2017-09-06|F106|2017-09-07**
```

I should only have the rows with between the `**`. 
The Question is how to extract them, what rule or condition should I create or how to extract the rest to leave only relevant. The condition for data with creating this was

```
   If FullDataSet$date[i] <= FullDataSet1$date[j]
```

So It's clear that the first date is earlier than the second one, but I don't want to have that many records. The new date should match the old date from next row.

Thank you for help. Best regards

Comment: what shout be the type of rows with `**`?

Comment: Something like `FullDataSet[!duplicated(FullDataSet[1:5]), ]`?

Comment: @SalmanLashkarara It doesn't matter pretty much because I can change it at the end. Can be characters can be date

Comment: @RuiBarradas it doesn't work because every row is unique. In general these are the change logs. So the rows in ** are those change logs, and other are changes from the future. ex. after "2017-09-05" next change was "2017-09-06" and the next one "2017-09-07". So rows that are not between ** are just later changes but to different dates

Comment: Which `class` are your data? A `data.frame`? If so, is it only one column `data.frame` or the | divides the columns?

Comment: @s_t class data.frame

Comment: The ** are written in your data or have you added to underline the rows you want?

Comment: I am **not** comparing the full rows, just the first 5 elements of each row. That's why it's `FullDataSet[1:5]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reproduced your situation by eliminating the asterisks from your text and reading from the file with

```
df <- read.table('text.txt', sep = '|')
```

You can check for unique rows on the first 5 columns.

```
df[which(!duplicated(df[,1:5])),]
```

Comment: <3 Did the similar thing. Thank you!